# Using tpm2.0-tools to encrypt data and extract

Tags: encryption, tpm

I just installed tpm2.0-tools on Ubuntu 20.04, but I don't know the commands like encrypt data, save to tpm or export data. I really appreciate any help.

Comment: What documentation did you read? The tools have manpages, there is a spec. Please ask more specific questions

Comment: https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tools/tree/master/man